# time picker container doesnt wrap its contents

Tags: jquery, css, timepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I use this time picker from [here](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/timepicker/#jquery-plugins)

everything works except its drop down time selection container doesnt wrap its children or its content like its height is collapse and its look awful. (refer to the image below)

[image]

and below is the css styles of the container/wrapper of the time picker

```
.bfh-timepicker-popover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Is there a fix for this? any help, suggestions, recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `float` property useful ? Can you remove it ?

If you want to keep it, try to add `overflow: hidden;` to the popup container.

Comment: thank you for the answer. now the height is wrapped the whole content but not its width (like the width of the parent is cut in half)

Comment: So I guess you used the `overflow` property ? Really, I think float isn't necessary at all to get this layout. Use `display: inline-block` instead when you want a DIV not to take the entire width.